# Software architecture/Design question, where to ask?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've noticed that every design/architecture question on Stack Overflow is closed as opinion based. Where should I ask my questions then?

Answer (score 4):

[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) seem a good fit for such questions.

To quote their help center;

> Software Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for
>   professionals, academics, and students working within the systems
>   development life cycle.
>
> If you have a question about...
>
> software development methods and practices
>       requirements, **architecture, and design**
>       quality assurance and testing
>       configuration management, build, release, and deployment
>
> ...then you're probably in the right place to ask your question.

They have a meta post too, to get an idea if your question could fit, it's there; [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/are-design-review-questions-on-topic).

Comment: Thanks, it sounds good. Surprised that you've been down-voted. And especially never got why these people down-vote not explaining why as it doesn't help! Up-voted you